# Would it be plausible for dark matter to be an undiscovered highly unreactive element with a high atomic number?

Tags: transuranic-elements

I had thought about posting something in physics stack, but I already know it's possible for dark matter to be here on earth, like they say it's all around us...

Comment: No, it wouldn't.

Comment: @Mithoron oh yea, of course... it isn't plausible for that... guess it's gotta be particles LOL

Comment: It's essentially impossible. Our best understanding of dark matter demands its particles to interact weakly through electromagnetism, so they cannot have electrical charges and therefore cannot be chemical elements as we know them.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Are you sure of that comment? I think that gets at the crux of it. I think you are in part wrong though. I think we know that it can't interact with normal matter but we have no idea what it even is let alone if it does interactions within it's own realm such as forming chemical elements.

Comment: I was going to extend my comment by mentioning "dark sectors" and "dark electromagnetism", which *could in principle maybe* contain additional "elements". However, a) these could not be chemical elements as we know them and would not go on the periodic table, and b) dark electromagnetism is present only in highly experimental models of dark matter.

Comment: If it were true, then creating the element in a particle accelerator would cause it to float away (cause it would stop interacting with e.g. your lab)...?

Comment: No, It is more likely all the energy lost from conversion of matter into energy since the formation of the Universe. We only see an infinitesimal amount of energy from nonexistant galaxies Where has all that energy gone

Answer (score 2):

No.

A chemically unreactive element would nonetheless have charged particles, interact with photons, and register electromagnetic emission/absorption spectra. In fact elements at the surface of stars like our Sun are generally in the form of atoms that are not chemically bound, and they are definitely not dark with respect to electromagnetic radiation. True dark matter does not have these properties.